# Jquery append html weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have the following ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myBaseUrl + 'Products/ajax_get_subcategories',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var length = data.length;
        var div_subcategory = $('#subcategory');
        div_subcategory.html('');
        div_subcategory.append(
            "<select id='subcategory' name='data[Product][subcategory_id]'>"
        );
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var id = data[i]['Subcategory']['id'];
            var name = data[i]['Subcategory']['name'];
            $('#subcategory').append(
                "<option value=''+id>" + name + "</option>"
            );
        }
        div_subcategory.append("</select>");
    }
});
```

Now as you can see it appends a `select` into a `div` block.

But! there is a catch here is the output of the HTML after the ajax has been called:

```
    div id="subcategory" class="subcategory">
<select id="subcategory" name="data[Product][subcategory_id]"></select>
<option +id="" value="">Telte</option>
<option +id="" value="">Toilet</option>
<option +id="" value="">Service</option>
<option +id="" value="">Borde</option>
<option +id="" value="">Stole</option>
<option +id="" value="">Lyd og lys</option>
</div>
```

As you can see it closes the select tag before adding the options.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Thats because jQuery will close the tags for you and you have 2 elements with the same id *(which is bad)*

Comment: how can i avoid automaticly closing the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
div_subcategory.append("<select id='subcategory' name='data[Product][subcategory_id]'>");
```

jQuery will insert

```
<select id='subcategory' name='data[Product][subcategory_id]'></select>
```

And becasue `div_subcategory` will have the same id as the select you will be matching the div instead.

Instead I would write this by creating the html in a string and injecting it all at once.

```
    var html += "<select id='subcategorysel' name='data[Product][subcategory_id]'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var id = data[i]['Subcategory']['id'];
        var name = data[i]['Subcategory']['name'];
        html += "<option value=''+id>" + name + "</option>";
    }
    html += "</select>";
    div_subcategory.append(html);
```

This snippet updates your code to use different ids and appends the html all in one go which should be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Try

change your success code

```
success: function (data) {
    var length = data.length;
    var div_subcategory = $('#subcategory');
    div_subcategory.html('');
    var select_append = "<select id='subcategory' name='data[Product][subcategory_id]'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var id = data[i]['Subcategory']['id'];
        var name = data[i]['Subcategory']['name'];
        select_append += "<option value=''" + id + ">" + name + "</option>";
    }
    select_append += "</select>"
    div_subcategory.append(select_append);
}
```

create a variable `select_append` and concatenate all your code in that and append that variable in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(div_subcategory).find('select').append(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you write this syntex

```
div_subcategory.append(
        "<select id='subcategory' name='data[Product][subcategory_id]'>"
    );
```

DOM automatically detects an HTML element like this

```
<select id='subcategory' name='xxx'></select>
```

and then you are appending other option elements after this

so solution is first make a string of an HTML and then append like

```
var html = "<select id='subcategory' name='data[Product][subcategory_id]'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var id = data[i]['Subcategory']['id'];
        var name = data[i]['Subcategory']['name'];
        html += "<option value='' + id>" + name + "</option>";
    }
    div_subcategory.append(html);
```